# get onlye name of string removing tags using regex mirc?

Tags: regex, mirc, usernametoken

i'm trying to catch only the nickname of a usernames on mirc usign regex but i cant catch this is the data which i want take the username

and in involve this regex code:

```
/^\x3a(:?(\[\w+\])?(\[\s\w+\s\]?))\s?(\w+)/i
```

Here is on regexer: [Regexer](http://regexr.com/3dkbg)

I would like get the username in Group 1.

so any body have an idea to catch this situations?

```
if ($regex(info,$1-,/^\x3a(?::?(?:\[\w+\])?(?:\[\s\w+\s\]?)?)?\s?(\w+) (CHAT) (#\S+) \x3a([\x21])(hi|test)( |$)/i)) {
echo * NickName: $regml(info,1)
echo * Method: $regml(info,2)
echo * Channel: $regml(info,3)
echo * Symbol: $regml(info,4)
echo * Trigger: $regml(info,5)  }
```

:[ Tag ] Xs_user CHAT #test_channel :!hi <- not work!
:madhu CHAT #test_channel :!hi <- this works

so in need to take only username to can compare if nick is operator of channel.

Comment: Add two more `?`: [`^\x3a(:?(\[\w+\])?(\[\s\w+\s\]?)?)?\s?(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tJ1nM8/1). Does it work for you like that? You have not mentioned what output you are trying to get. User name will be in Group 4 if you use this regex.

Comment: thank you, i would like get the username  in the group 1, could be this  possible?

Comment: yes let me try to implement your answer! thanks in advance

Comment: on mirc this only get the username but when have not tags :( im go to put a more especific expample.

Comment: Yes, please make your question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two more `?` to make `(:?(\[\w+\])?(\[\s\w+\s\]))` and `(\[\w+\])?(\[\s\w+\s\]?)` groups optional:

```
^\x3a(:?(\[\w+\])?(\[\s\w+\s\]?)?)?\s?(\w+)
                                ^ ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ1nM8/1). The user name will be in Group 4 if you use this regex.

**To get the user  name into Group 1**, use *non-capturing* groups for all groupings you are not interested in by adding `?:` after opening `(`:

```
^\x3a(?::?(?:\[\w+\])?(?:\[\s\w+\s\]?)?)?\s?(\w+)
      ^^   ^^          ^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ1nM8/2)